# Infiniti active lane keeping inquiry

Tags: infiniti, active-lane-assist

I own a 2019 Infiniti q60 red sport fully loaded. It seems that the active lane assist basically only works when you are going around 100kh. Can it be recalibrated to work much sooner. My wife's Kia starts working around 35kh.